# Change all values in one column of a dataframe lower than X to 0, and X and all values greater than X to 1

Tags: r

I'm sure this is simple but my R isn't up to it: how can I change all values in one column of a dataframe lower than X to 0, and X and all values greater than X to 1?

Comment: Good point - I should have said lower than X to 0, X or above to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ifelse](http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/Rhelp/ifelse.html) function does exactly what you want. If your dataframe is called `d`, and the column called `d$column`:

```
d$column = ifelse(d$column < X, 0, 1)
```